# Making 24 with given number N

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Initially we have a sequence of n integers: 1, 2, ..., n. In a single step, we can pick two of them, let's denote them a and b, erase them from the sequence, and append to the sequence either a + b, or a - b, or a × b.

After n - 1 steps there is only one number left. Can we make this number equal to 24

Example : Let n=8 then answer is YES

Steps are :

```
8 * 7 = 56
6 * 5 = 30
3 - 4 = -1
1 - 2 = -1
30 - -1 = 31
56 - 31 = 25
25 + -1 = 24
```

So for given n we need to find if its possible and also find the steps followed.

Comment: we can say for any given n greater than 8 it is possible as we can do d same steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can reduce the problem for $n$ to the problem for $n-2$ in two steps:

$$\begin{align}
n-(n-1)&=1\\
(n-2)\times1&=n-2\\
\end{align}$$

Thus if $n\gt2$ is even, you can reduce it to the case $n=4$ in $n-4$ steps, at which point three multiplications finishes things off.  If $n\gt3$ is odd, then you can reduce it to the case $n=5$ in $n-5$ steps, at which point you can get to $24$ in the following $4$ steps:

$$\begin{align}
5-1&=4\\
4-2&=2\\
4\times2&=8\\
8\times3&=24
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

First suppose that $n$ is even (for example, $12$). Then you can have

```
12 - 11 = 1
10 - 9 = 1
-------------Your steps--------------
8 * 7 = 56
6 * 5 = 30
3 - 4 = -1
1 - 2 = -1
30 - -1 = 31
56 - 31 = 25
25 + -1 = 24  
-----------------------------------------
24 * 1 = 24
24 * 1 = 24
```

Hence any even number over $8$ would work.

I couldn't think of a general algorithm for odd numbers, only for specific cases.